# Is the below a Java Multiple Inheritance Design Pattern if yes which one?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have been working in a Swing application for more than 8 years but it was designed perhaps 20 years ago, the designers created their own custom made components (I think initially using AWT but it was updated to Swing at some stage).

There is a widget used by multiple screens that presents data in a Gantt Chart stile that allows for user interaction, drag and drop among other things. A simplified depiction of this design is as below:

```
//Many lines of implementation code and only 1 constructor
public class GanttChartImplementation extends JPanel {

  public GanttChartImplementation(String p1, Object p2, boolean p3, boolean p4){
    //Implementation code
  }

}


//No implementation only constructors
public class GanttChartInterface extends GanttChartImplementation {

  public GanttChartInterface(String p1, Object p2, boolean p3, boolean p4) {
    super(p1,p2,p3,p4);
  }

  public GanttChartInterface(String p1, Object p2, boolean p3) {
    super(p1,p2,p3,true); //defaults p4 to true as it's not passed in
  }

  public GanttChartInterface(String p1, Object p2) {
    super(p1,p2,true,true); //defaults p3, p4 to true as these are not passed in
  }
}
```

All the screens in the application will extend GanttChartInterface that its first obvious use is to hide the implementation class from the screens that use the Gantt Chart widget. Even in theory GanttChartInterface may be changed to extend a different implementation class without having to change the screens that use the Gantt Chart widget.

Another benefit about this design, that I have found over the years, is that when adding a new parameter to the constructor in GanttChartImplementation class then screens that use the widget don't need to be changed because It's only required to modify existing constructors in GanttChartInterface so they set the new param value to a default and then will create a new constructor, in example as below:

```
//Add new parameter to constructor used to have 4 now 5
public class GanttChartImplementation extends JPanel {

   public GanttChartImplementation(String p1, Object p2, boolean p3, boolean p4, boolean p5){
     //Implementation code
   }

}
```

Only need to modify GanttChartInterface so it compiles and there is no need to change any of pre-existing screens that use the widget:

```
//No implementation only constructors had 3 constructors now has 4
public class GanttChartInterface extends GanttChartImplementation {

  //Create new constructor that receives the new parameter
  public GanttChartInterface(String p1, Object p2, boolean p3, boolean p4, boolean p5) {
    super(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5); 
  }

  public GanttChartInterface(String p1, Object p2, boolean p3, boolean p4) {
    super(p1,p2,p3,p4,true); //defaults p5 to true as it's not passed in
  }

  public GanttChartInterface(String p1, Object p2, boolean p3) {
     super(p1,p2,p3,true,true); //defaults p4, p5 to true as these are not passed in
  }

  public GanttChartInterface(String p1, Object p2) {
     super(p1,p2,true,true,true); //defaults p3, p4, p5 to true as these are not passed in
  }
}
```

I have looked at many articles around the web and SO questions and this doesn't seem to be a GoF design pattern and haven't found anywhere if this is a widespread used design pattern or not? I am trying to find information as I would like to know who came up with this design. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This seems to be some sort of inheritance as factory antipattern. I think that whoever wrote this fell headfirst into OO explosion of the 90s and 00s and it suffers from all the problems that that entails. All your advantages sound like - to me - disadvantages. You need to change code in the wrong place to make changes; you have direct references to implementations and need to change inheritance hierarchies to make simple changes to the factory logic. And last but not least this is untestable as there is no way to swap out implementations to do unit testing.

Comment: Well i'd call it convenience constructor overloading or default values. They just allowed to take on default values. In order for you to have an easier life when calling.  But I also do C++ so that might seem more natural to me than to Java purists(in the best sence of the term of cause). - Odd is calling it an Interface however as it clearly is not.

Comment: It looks a bit like an attempt to use the Delegation pattern, but using inheritance instead of the usual delegate. A probably better design would have been for GanttChartInterface to be an interface and GanttChartImplementation to implement it.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers I have clear picture now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OOP it is a overloaded constructor to provide default values.

**EDIT**
Like @boris mentioned in comments.
You dont need to use subclass to overload method you can simply do it in GanttChartImplementation. No benefit from inheritance here. Just unecessary class.

Comment: The antipattern is using an empty inheritor on a implementation to specify the constructor overloads. This is what I have called "_inheritance as factory antipattern_". The use of constructor overloads is just a small part of this antipattern.

Comment: An anti-pattern is a common response to a recurring problem that is usually ineffective and risks being highly counterproductive.

Comment: What is the risk here or it is somethong contraproductive?

Comment: It is know that overuse of inheritance for "utility" is an antipattern, see for example the Constant Interface Antipattern. There is a large literature about preferring composition over inheritance due to the cost inheritance and the complexity it entails. Using inheritance as some naive form of homebrew DI is not only an antipattern it prevents sane testing and requires changes to inheritance hierarchies to change the instance used.

Comment: Imagine if I create a `class BorisCollection` that had loads of overloaded constructors and I advocated its advantage that it currently inherits from `ArrayList` but I can change it to inherit from `LinkedList` if I needed to change the implementation of list my code uses surely you would say "_that's a really weird antipattern, why are you doing that??_".

Comment: OP wants to inherit parent class and to not break functionality in subclasses. He changes parent and using a new parameter in constructor he will turn on/off this changes. This will not break functionality in subclasses. 

Yes doing just overloading in separate subclass is overuse of inheritance. He can simply overload it in GanttChartImplementation.

Comment: That's part of it, yes. But the reason for the empty implementation class with just the ctors is so "_in theory `GanttChartInterface` may be changed to extend a different implementation class without having to change the screens that use the `GanttChart` widget._" So there are two stated "advantages" of this pattern. 1) ability to add parameters without breaking existing usages 2) ability to change the parent class without changing the consumers. My argument is that both points are spurious and solved correctly with known patterns (IoC and Factory) and using inheritance for this purpose...

Comment: ...is an antipattern. I also think that using overloading in this way is not great, and sign of poorly designed code. But that's not my primary issue with the published antipattern.